# .net core web api 500 error and can't hit breakpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a manager class:

```
 public class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    private readonly IGraphApiClient _client;
    private readonly IUserDataProvider _userDataProvider;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public UserManager(IGraphApiClient client, IMapper mapper, IUserDataProvider _userDataProvider)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _client = client;
        _userDataProvider = userDataProvider;           
    }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAssociatedCustomersByUserEmail(string email)
    {
        var customers = _userDataProvider.GetAssociatedCustomersByUserEmail(email);
        return customers;
    }
```

And when I *remove* the `IUserDataProvider _userDataProvider` in the UserManager constructor signature and the `_userDataProvider = userDataProvider;` my web api will "work" in the sense that I can get a breakpoint to hit and I can call an endpoint. An exception is obviously thrown inside the `GetAssociatedCustomerByUserEmail()` because I did not inject the IUserDataProvider.

And when I keep these lines of code in, all my web API will return is 500 error status and I **cannot hit any breakpoints**.

At first I realized I forgot to register the IUserDataProvider, but even after doing so in my startup.cs I still get the same problem.

```
        services.AddScoped<IUserDataProvider, UserDataProvider>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserManager, UserManager>();
```

Everything else... all my controllers, managers, dataproviders, etc work *except* for this specific one. I cannot figure it out. I've checked all my accessor (public vs private) everywhere and they are seem legit. I've run out of things to investigate at this point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install `Install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics` from nuget

Change your `Configure` method in `startup.cs` to below, then you will see the error message

pay attention that it should be before any other lines

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        env.EnvironmentName = EnvironmentName.Development;
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
        }

        app.UseStatusCodePages();
```

More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling

Comment: Thank You!! That led me to what I needed to know. I didn't register something a little deeper down ;)  will accept as answer in a couple min

Answer (score 3):

I was bit by this issue today. Using Dependency injection and did not register a class in my startup that my controller was using.